# Can't assign -2147483648 to variable of type long long

Tags: c

I'm compiling the code below and for some reason I can't assign -2147483648 to the variable which is 8 bytes long and signed.

```
long long x = -2147483648;
```

When I step over this line, the value of x is 2147483648 and the 'Watch' window in MS Visual Studio shows that the type of x is __int64. A sizeof(x) also returns 8.

According to limit.h the limits for a signed long long are:

```
#define LLONG_MAX     9223372036854775807i64       /* maximum signed long long int value */
#define LLONG_MIN   (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)  /* minimum signed long long int value */
```

and:

```
/* minimum signed 64 bit value */
#define _I64_MIN    (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
/* maximum signed 64 bit value */
#define _I64_MAX      9223372036854775807i64
```

I just don't get it!!!

Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: I think you just need the "LL" literal. so `long long x = -2147483648LL;`

Comment: @David: Yes MS Visual Studio. What's the deal with them?

Comment: That is not a real C compiler. The C++ compiler is fine, but the C compiler is some vague approximation to C89, and not a very good one at that. All bets are off when compiling in C mode.

Comment: For me in GCC, this code compiles but produces the wrong result: it comes out with the right magnitude but the number is *positive*. I really don't get it.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. I hope somebody can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the LL, the compiler appears to deduce `2147483648` is a 32-bit `unsigned long`.  *Then* it applies the `-` operator.  The result is `0 - 2147483648`.  Since this is less than 0 and being an `unsigned long t`, `4294967296` is added, which is `2147483648` again.  This value is then assigned to `long long x`.

Suggest:

```
long long x = -2147483648LL;
// or
long long x = -2147483647  - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning to -2147483648LL

see Integer constants [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But why is the compiler not able to figure it out by itself? The type is clearly long long, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles and executes fine on my GCC 4.6.3 compiler, with --std=c99. I suspect that you are using the rather hopeless so-called C compiler that Microsoft supply. It obviously isn't very clever. Use a long long suffix (`i64`, `ll` or `LL`) to trick it into behaving.

Interestingly the MS C++ compiler cannot get this right either:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long x = -2147483647;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x = -2147483648;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x = -2147483649;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
-2147483647
2147483648
2147483647
```

I compiled this with the x86 C++ compiler from VS2013.

And I get the same output from my g++ 4.6.3.

So I think there is more to this than meets the eye. I hope somebody that knows more than me could explain all this.

Comment: Wow. That's is crazy.

Comment: I hope so too. I would like to understand this better.

Comment: Could I possibly requestion that you unaccept my answer. I don't think it is a very good answer. I would hope somebody who knows this stuff much better than me will come along and give a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to some of the other comments (sorry, can't reply to each of them as I don't have enough rep yet):

In C and C++ the type of an expression doesn't depend on its context. In this case, the type of     `-214743648` is defined by the language rules,  the fact that you later assign it to a `long long` doesn't affect this.

Actually this way of doing things makes the language much simpler than the alternative, it's one of the things that attracted me to C in the first place.

In David Heffernan's example,

```
x = -2147483648;
std::cout << x << std::endl;     // gives 2147483648
x = -2147483649;
std::cout << x << std::endl;     // gives 2147483647
```

The important thing is that the `-` sign is NOT part of an integer literal. The expression `2147483648` is an integer constant whose type is determined according to a set of rules in the standard; and then the unary minus operator is applied to the value (which does not change its type).

Unfortunately, C90, C99, C++98 and C++11 all have different rules for the types of integer literals. Further, the rules are different for decimal constants than for hex or octal constants! You can look them up in the relevant standards documents.

If you have 32-bit ints, then `2147483648` is too large to be an `int`. In all dialects the next possible type for it is `long int`. If you also have 32-bit `long ints`, then in C99 or C++11 it has type `long long int`. In C90 or C++98 it has type `unsigned long int`. (Those languages do not have a `long long` type).

Back to David Heffernan's example. C++98 does not have `long long`, so either you're using a C++11 compiler, or using Microsoft extensions. Assuming the latter; who knows what they've decided to do for integer constants, but if they have retained the C++98 definition that `2147483648` has type `unsigned long int`, that would explain the results.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I just had to write it like this:

```
long long x = -2147483648i64;
```

Why is the compiler not able to figure it out. I already spelled out the type, so why do I have to put 'i64' after the number ???

Comment: You're probably using an old compiler, or one with poor C support.

Comment: @Dietrich: I'm using the compiler that goes with MS Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: That explains it.  The Visual Studio compiler has notoriously poor support for the C language.  Other compilers will automatically figure it out, which has been required by the C specification since 1999.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Interestingly the MS C++ compiler cannot manage this either.

Comment: Looks like GCC has similar problems based on the posts from the other guys ?

Comment: No, GCC does not have this problem.  It's pretty much just the Microsoft C compiler that has this problem.