# Data type `long` in C programming

Tags: c

What is the difference between
`long int numberOfPoints = 131071100;` and
`long int numberOfPoints = 131071100L;`

and is an assignment such as
`int numberOfPoints = 131071100L;`
legal? And if it is what is the difference between that and the previous two?

Comment: If you really need "long" (not "int"), then you *MUST* declare (all!) your long variables "long", and you *MUST* declare your integer literals "L".  Or you risk "silently truncating" one or the other.

Comment: Without the suffix, things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295313/cant-assign-2147483648-to-variable-of-type-long-long?rq=1) can happen.

Comment: but is it necessary to declare it as `long int numberOfPoints = 131071100L;` i.e. is it necessary to declare the variable with the `long` prefix and the `L` appended to the end of the number? Or does declaring `long int numberOfPoints = 131071100;` or `int numberOfPoints = 131071100L;` accomplish the same task(making it a `long` variable)?

Comment: @FoggyDay: In this case, the suffix is not necessary, though it's not a bad idea if you want to be explicit. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23069464/827263).

Comment: My experience with other compilers on different platforms over the years is that often times the "L" *can* sometimes be necessary.  IMHO...

Comment: @FoggyDay: Yes, it's sometimes necessary (again, see my answer), but it's not in this particular case. The only way it would make any difference *for this example* is if the OP is using a non-conforming compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The type of an unsuffixed integer constant like `131071100` is the first of `int`, `long int`, and `long long int` in which its value can be represented. The value of `131071100` is *always* mathematically correct; only its type varies (and since `long int` is at least 32 bits, it's always either an `int` or a `long int`).

With the `L` suffix, it's of type `long int` or `long long int`; again, the value is always correct -- and it happens that `131071100L` is always of type `long int`.

It's perfectly valid to initialize an object of some arithmetic type with an expression of a different numeric type. The value is implicitly *converted* to the target type. And in this case, since the target type is `long int`, there is no risk of overflow.

For your particular case, the *only* difference between

```
long int numberOfPoints = 131071100;
```

and

```
long int numberOfPoints = 131071100L;
```

is that the latter is slightly more explicit; the meaning is exactly the same.

The `L` suffix is still needed if the expression is more complicated than a single constant.  For example, if you write:

```
long int foo = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

then each constant `1024` is of type `int` -- and so is the entire expression. If `int` happens to be just 16 bits, then the multiplication will overflow, even though the *mathematical* result would fit in a `long int`. (The type of a literal is adjusted depending on its value; the type of a large expression is not.) To avoid that problem, you can write:

```
long int foo = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;
```

Answer (score 1):

(A previous answer here was incorrect and has been amended.)

Per the ANSI C specification (similar language exists in C99 and C++ specifications):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list
> in which its value can be represented.
>
> Unsuffixed decimal: int, long
> int, unsigned long int.
>
> Unsuffixed octal or hexadecimal: int, unsigned
> int, long int, unsigned long int.
>
> Suffixed by the letter u or U: unsigned int, unsigned long int.
>
> Suffixed by the letter l or L: long
> int, unsigned long int.
>
> Suffixed by both the letters u or U and l or L: unsigned long int.

Therefore, there will not be any difference between the two expressions, since C guarantees that the constant's type will be long enough to hold the value.