# Can't Assign 64 Bit Number to 64 Bit Min in C++

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I'm new to C++, so sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I'm attempting to assign the 64 bit minimum (-9223372036854775808) to an int64_t (from cstdint), however I'm getting the current error message:

```
main.cpp:5:27: warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]
int64_t int_64_min = -9223372036854775808;
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    int64_t int_64_min = -9223372036854775808;
    std::cout << int_64_min << std::endl;
    std::cout << INT64_MIN << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `9223372036854775808` is too large to fit in a 64 bit integer. `-` is an operator applied to the number, it doesn't mean the number is parsed as negative. Also if this is C++ then please us `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::min()` from `<limits>` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't assign -2147483648 to variable of type long long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295313/cant-assign-2147483648-to-variable-of-type-long-long)

Comment: @AdrianMole That's simply not true. The suffix doesn't matter here. "The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which integer-suffix was used. " Please refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal. Here the smallest such type is an unsigned 64 bit integer (I should have been more clear earlier and say 64 bit *signed* integer)

Comment: look at the table under the link please. In the case of no suffix all integer types are listed.

Comment: (Note that Java has different rules for integer constants - if you're from such a background then you might find the C++ rules surprising. Above all, welcome to C++!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *exactly* why the `INT_MIN` family of macros are often defined like `-INT_MAX - 1` on a 2's complement platform (virtually ubiquitous and compulsory from C++20).

There is no such thing as a negative literal in C++: just the unary negation of a positive number which produces a compile time evaluable constant expression.

`9223372036854775808` is too big to fit into a 64 bit signed integral type, so the behavior of negating this and assigning to a signed 64 bit integral type is implementation defined.

Writing `-9223372036854775807 - 1` is probably what your C++ standard library implementation does. If I were you, I'd use `INT64_MIN` directly or `std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min()`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `-9223372036854775808` is not a literal. `9223372036854775808` is a literal, and `-9223372036854775808` is an expression consisting of that literal with a unary `-` applied to it.

All unsuffixed decimal literals are of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`. Since `9223372036854775808` is 2<sup>63</sup>, it's bigger than the maximum value of `long long int` (assuming `long long int` is 64 bits, which it almost certainly is).

The simplest solution is to use the `INT64_MIN` macro defined in `<cstdint>`.

Aside from that, the problem is that there are no literals for negative values. Another solution is to replace `-9223372036854775808` by `-9223372036854775807-1` -- or by `(-9223372036854775807-1)` to avoid ambiguity. (The `<cstdint>` header very likely does something similar).